# Can no longer open terminal after editing my bash_aliases

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, bash-alias

I edited my bash_aliases to have a new alias (stars block out my email for privacy sake):

```
alias t_cluster="u*******@notchpeak.chpc.utah.edu"
```

I then mistakenly added this to my bash_aliases (when I meant to add it to my bashrc):

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
. ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

As soon as I saved and exited the bash_aliases my terminal shut down and will no longer open. I am fairly new to programming and need help understanding how to get terminal working again.. I don't know where to start

Ctrl+Alt+T will bring terminal window up but it won't actually open, it pops up and immediately closes

The actual Terminal icon does the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Ubuntu due to `gnome-terminal` being present in flags.

**For Ubuntu 20.04**

Hold the super key (Win-key), hit E       *(nautilus, the gnome "file explorer" starts)*
Find the "three-bar"-menu button in the upper right, click it.
Select "Show hidden files"
Right click `.bash_aliases` in the list of files, select `Open with text editor`.

*This has to be done differently in earlier Ubuntu versions, might be the same for 20.10 at least...*

Comment: This worked.  Thank you very much.